# Why is it so easy to decrypt MD5 checksums

Tags: md5

I have recently been plyaing aroud with a website that converts MD5 to the plain text format. Why is it so easy to decrypt it ?

Take this example

```
8466fa8e428bf83c4d2d9893b4bada64

7d53cbd3f0c0e2af31c3ba1eab940f22

dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964

27d4cf7da57f6748f79254f7be42cca3

909cea0c97058cfe2e3ea8d675cb08e1
```

Decrypts to "My gmail password is orange" in under 1 second.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukGwh.png)

Even with sha256 it got decrypted instantly
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sYY5.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*md5* is a one-way digest function, also known as a hash function. It is not an encryption mechanism.

*md5* is known to have several weaknesses, and common advice has been to avoid using it for over a decade now.

On this particular site, you are likely seeing an example of rainbow tables being used to find collisions, or perhaps even the original inputs. Rainbow tables work by precomputing very large amounts of likely inputs (such as known passwords, the entire dictionary for multiple languages, common word combinations, etc). Such tables can be efficiently searched for a given hash to find an input that produces said hash.

Note that in some cases, you may receive a different result from the rainbow table from what you used as the input. In this case, it is also an example of a collision.

It is possible to protect against rainbow attacks using salting, which adds random data to each input, such that a precomputed rainbow table is unlikely to have your exact input in it.

Although *md5* is considered broken, it is not broken to the extent that you can perform a direct "decryption" given a hash - most attacks attempt to produce collisions as opposed to finding preimages.

For any security sensitive applications, you should consider using modern hash functions such as *sha256*. For password hashing, consider using hash functions specifically designed for password hashing, such as *bcrypt*.

Comment: Even with sha256 it got decrypyed in under 1 second

Comment: Again, it is very likely using a rainbow table attack. Any hash function will be vulnerable to a rainbow table by definition, as long as the table contains the input. If you try md5 or sha256 with some random data, `r8p,j9fwjp9fjewp9,qhzh.wphg9whreegc9,wgrp.9e8rxphrew9,xujvsmudsh9mo84ahpch9,vpjr9x.hgp9re.x` for example, it will not be able to provide the input.

Answer (score 3):

Because md5 is not an encryption mechanism, it is a very old one-way hash algorithm. What you are finding are collisions, and they are highly unlikely to be the original input. They have produced **a** possible match. Consider

```
$ echo "My Gmail Password Is Orange" | md5sum
97ec87f89796b683feae88008c302d22  -
$ echo -n "My Gmail Password Is Orange" | md5sum
52b4551c065189631be8b506eee9b62e  -
```

The only difference between those two `String`(s) is the newline. It's true that md5 is broken. But it's not reversible, unless you consider very short words and a dictionary.

Comment: Frisch It is the original inout

Comment: @F.Ahmed For trivial sample words. What does it give you for 8a2c1ee4c9faf18992a59cedd9023349? BTW, if that comes back fast, it's still only an example of a rainbow table at work. That was "floccinaucinihilipilification", now try 8a2c1ee4c9faf18992a59cedd9023350.

Comment: Frisch it comes to floccinaucinihilipilification

Comment: @F.Ahmed *How it works ?
MD5 means a 128-bit encryption algorithm, generating a 32-character hexadecimal hash, whatever the captcha. This algorithm is not reversible, ie it is normally impossible to find the original word from the md5 hash. Our tool uses a huge database in order to have the best chance possible to trace the captcha. Just enter an MD5 hash in the form above to try to decrypt! 

Words in the database : 1,154,869,433,999* From [here](https://www.md5online.org/).

Comment: It's a big rainbow table. SALT your passwords folks!